# bash script with ls $variable

Tags: bash

I'm trying to get my script to ls all the files in the form "$variable".*

the parameter is always a file with the extension .001
I want to find all the files with the same name but different extension, eg $file.002, file.003 etc. eg.:

```
first="$1"
others=${first%.001}
ls $others"*"
```

My problem is the file is named `file[success].mpg.001`
and what gets fed to ls is `file[success].mpg*` which gives me 
`ls: cannot access file[success].mpg*: No such file or directory`
because `ls` needs to see:

```
file\[success\].mpg*
```

I've been trying everything, the one thing I did notice is
ls fed the parameter $1 works, but not if fed $file after I've done file=$1 .
So I guess how do I change the variable into a parameter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `bash`'s `printf` command to reformat the string. Furthermore you don't need to quote `*`:

```
#!/bin/bash
first="$1"
others=$(printf %q "${first%.001}")
ls $others*
```

`printf %q` reformats the string in a format that can be used as shell input (regarding to `bash`'s man page).

*edit regarding to a comment*:
The above solution does not work with white spaces in file names. For those cases (as some other answers already mentioned) it's better not to use `printf` but to properly quote all variables:

```
#!/bin/bash
first="$1"
others="${first%.001}"
ls -- "$others"*
```

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you.

Comment: This works for files with brackets in the names, but not for other odd characters like spaces.  For example, I tried `./findfiles1 "test [success].mpg.001"`, and it parsed that as two filenames and didn't find either: `ls: \[success\].mpg*: No such file or directory` `ls: test\: No such file or directory`.

Comment: @Gordon: You are right. This doesn't work with spaces/tabs. For those cases it's better to go with the solution mentioned by Philipp or Kaleb to do something like `ls -- "${first%.001}"*`. I will add this to my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You should quote the variable, not the wildcard:

```
ls -- "$others"*
```

The double dash stops search for options so that this code should work even if `others` begins with a dash.

Note that `ls` is more often than not the wrong solution in scripts. Use it only if you really want to print the list, e.g. in long format:

```
ls -l -- "$others"*
```

If you want to print only the names, you don't need `ls` at all:

```
echo "$others"*
```

Unfortunately you cannot use `--` with `echo`.
If, however, you want an array of the file names, use

```
filenames=("$others"*)
```

And should you want to iterate over them, use

```
for filename in "$others"*
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not too far off. My first fix is changing line 3 to the following:

```
ls -- "${others}".*
```

This will expand `$others` and allow the globbing to happen.  It's the shells responsibility to expand the `*` to the list of all matching filenames.  The list of filenames is then sent to `ls`.  It sounds like in most cases ls will see something like this:

```
file1.001 file1.002 file1.003 ...
```

But, when no files are present, the shell passes the glob to ls and it will see asterisk:

```
file1.*
```

Thus, your line, `ls $others"*"` appends a literal asterisk which ls will see.

Unless you have a file name `file1.*` (with a literal asterisks), `ls` will fail.

Another option is to use basename:

```
first="$1"
others=`basename -- "$first" .001`
ls -- "${others}".*
```

Using `basename` gives you the advantage that it can remove directories, etc.

However, as others have pointed out, depending on what you're doing with the list of files, `find` may be better.

EDIT: The double-hyphen doesn't work on all *nix variants but tells the `ls` and `basename` commands that no other cli arguments follow. Quoting your variables may be a best practices but I prefer the simplicity of leaving them off unless the data isn't trusted. Know your data and quote appropriately.

Comment: Your variables are not properly quoted, which causes issues if the file names contain spaces or other "special" characters. Use `ls -- "$others"*` and `basename -- "$first"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use find instead ls:

```
$ ls weg.*
ls: weg.*: No such file or directory
$ find . -name weg.\*
$
```

Comment: find . -name file[success].mpg* doesnt find anything.

Comment: from l0b0's answer i guess i should just use a different way than ls